# How to whitelist/blacklist child object fields in the ModelBinder/UpdateModel method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a question regarding how to get the white- and black-listing feature of the MVC controller's UpdateModel/TryUpdateModel to work on individual properties of child objects. For example, lets say I have a questionnaire collecting details about the person filling out the form and about his or her company.

My [simplified] form fields would be named, for example:

```
YourName
YourEmail
Company.Name
Company.Phone
```

Now in my model, lets say I don't want Company.ID or Company.IsPremiumMember to be tampered with, so I'd like to exclude them from the model-binding. I have tried a combination of whitelisting, blacklisting, and both in order to get this to work. I have not had any success. Here is what I am running into:

When I explicitly include in my whitelist the same four fieldnames I wrote above, the entire Company does not get bound (i.e., questionnaire.Company is left null) unless I also include "Company" in my whitelist. But then this has the undesirable effect of binding the ENTIRE company, and not just the two properties I want.

So, I then tried to include Company.ID and Company.IsPremiumMember in my blacklist, but this seems to be trumped by the whitelist and does not filter out these properties "after the fact" I suppose.

I know that there are other ways to express the "bindability", such as via the [Bind] attribute on members, but this is not ideal as I would like to have the same model classes used in other situations with different binding rules, such as allowing an admin to set whatever properties she would like.

I expect an obvious answer is that I should write my own model binder, and I've already starting trying to look into how to perhaps do this, but I was really hoping to use an "out-of-the-box" solution for what (in my opinion) seems like a very common scenario. Another idea I'm pondering is to fabricate my own ValueProvider dictionary to hand to the UpdateModel method, but again, something I'd rather avoid if there is an easier way.

Thanks for any help!
-Mike

---

***Addendum #1***

*Here are the fields I present on my form:*

```
YourName
YourEmail
Company.Name
Company.Phone
```

*And here is what a black hat sends my way:*

```
YourName=Joe+Smith&YourEmail=joe@example.com&Company.Name=ACME+Corp&Company.Phone=555-555-5555&Company.CreditLimit=10000000
```

(be sure you notice the extra parameter tacked on there at the end!)

*And here is the problem:*

As I originally posted, it doesn't seem possible (using the default model binder) to prevent CreditLimit from being set---it's either the entire Company or nothing---without some big workaround. Am I wrong?

---

***Addendum #2***

I'm pretty much convinced now that the simple objective I have is not possible "out of the box." My solution has been to walk through the posted form fields and construct my own ValueProvider dictionary, thus whitelisting the fields I want to allow, and handing that to UpdateModel.

---

***Addendum #3***

I still have not yet checked out AutoMapper, but with something like that at hand, the solution of creating some ViewModels/DTOs to handle this type of complex whitelisting---plus the ability to easily attach the same server-side validation (FluentValidation) I'm already using on my domain objects---seems a viable solution. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the best way to go is to create **view-models**, models built *specifically for your views*. These models are *not* domain objects. They are data-transfer objects, built to transfer data from your controller actions to your view templates. You can use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) painlessly to create/update a domain model object from your view-model object or to create/update a view-model object from your domain model.

Comment: AutoMapper looks like an excellent utility that would indeed simplify this. I'm going to check it out later this evening. Thanks!

Comment: I've also found that UpdateModel comes in a generic form, UpdateModel<T>, which I found on another post here at S.O. that recommends creating an interface T that can act as a whitelist. I did not see this technique in either of the MVC books I have read, but it seems like it might have some promise. (Perhaps no more effort than creating a handful of DTOs.) P.S. this other post I referenced is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924424/difference-using-updatemodel-and-modelbinding-in-parameter

Comment: If you use the view-model pattern, you can also perform powerful server-side validation on the strictly typed view-model (instead of on Request.Form or FormCollection fields) using libraries such as Castle.Components.Validator or FluentValidation.

Comment: Scott Guthrie blogged about using an interface as a whitelist: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx#five

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around this problem by making the action accepting two objects (the parent and the child object)

Example:
Suppose we have the following model:

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Company Comapany { get; set; }
    }
    public class Company
    {
        public int Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

You build your form like this:

```
    <form action="Home/Create" method="post">
   <label for="Employee.Name">Name</label>
    <%=Html.TextBox("Employee.Name") %><br />
   <label for="Employee.Name">Age</label>    
    <%=Html.TextBox("Employee.Age") %><br />
   <label for="Employee.Name">Comapany Phone</label>    
    <%=Html.TextBox("Company.Phone") %><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
   </form>
```

Then build a "Create" action that accept two objects one of type Employee and the other of type Comapny and assign the Company object to the Employee.Company property inside the action:

```
 public ActionResult Create(Employee employee,Company company)
        {
            employee.Comapany = company;
            UpdateModel(employee);
            return View();
        }
```

I hope this help you.

**Edit:**

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee,Company company)
{
   employee.Comapany = company;
   UpdateModel(employee,new[] {"Name","Email","Phone"});
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I'm not having any problems binding the model: my problem is trying to restrict what in the model gets bound. It seems that in your example, without supplying either a whitelist or blacklist (or other equivalent) to the UpdateModel method, someone could still set Company.IsPremiumMember by injecting this into their form post.

Comment: Then the solution is to pass the list of properties you want to include to the UpdateModel method.
I will update my answer

Comment: I added an addendum to my original post. (See especially the last line.) The problem more appropriately seems like an "all or nothing" on the Company property...

Comment: A minor point, but in the form example above, the text boxes id attibutes will be rendered with underscores instead of a periods, so the label for tags need to be modified accordingly. ex: <label for="Employee_Name">Name</label>

Comment: Thank you Marwan, I do see that your latest edit does technically accomplish what I'm looking for. Since I have about eight or nine objects (all as children of the Company) however, it does not seem very appealing to have to account for all of these in such a manner. The solution I came up with seems, in my case, to allow me to only have to deal with one white list and one "UpdateModel" call, and can also avoid having to "re-attach" all of my objects afterwards. I'll also be able to re-use my own whitelisting technique on the rest of the pages I still have left to build!  Thanks again!

Comment: btw your input names are wrong, the should match the parameter name, not the type i.e. starting letters should be lower cases

Comment: No, the input names must be the same as the type members names.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following?:

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="PropertyToExclude1, PropertyToExclude2")] Employee employee) 
{

//action code here

}

or use Include instead of Exclude to List what fields can be bound rather than which can't

Comment: Hello, as shown in my original post, the issue is not that I can't exclude "PropertyToExclude1". The issue is that I can't exclude "SomeParent.SomeProperty" in this manner.