# Selectively Whitelisting Model Fields to Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

(I realize this question is very similar to [How to whitelist/blacklist child object fields in the ModelBinder/UpdateModel method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957840/how-to-whitelist-blacklist-child-object-fields-in-the-modelbinder-updatemodel-me) but my situation is slightly different and there may be a better solution available now that wasn't then.)

Our company sells web-based software that is extremely configurable by the end-user.  The nature of this flexibility means that we must do a number of things at *run time* that would normally be done at compile time.

There are some rather complex rules regarding who has read or read/write access to most everything.

For instance, take this model that we would like to create:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace j6.Business.Site.Models
{
    public class ModelBindModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Whitelist(ReadAccess = true, WriteAccess = true)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Whitelist(ReadAccess = true, WriteAccess = true)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Whitelist(ReadAccess = true, WriteAccess = true)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Whitelist(ReadAccess = User.CanReadSalary, WriteAccess = User.CanWriteSalary)]
        public string Salary { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Whitelist(ReadAccess = User.CanReadSsn, WriteAccess = User.CanWriteSsn)]
        public string Ssn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string SirNotAppearingOnThisPage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the controller, it is not difficult to "unbind" things manually.

```
var resetValue = null;
modelState.Remove(field);

pi = model.GetType().GetProperty(field);
if (pi == null)
{
    throw new Exception("An exception occured in ModelHelper.RemoveUnwanted.  Field " +
    field  +
    " does not exist in the model " + model.GetType().FullName);
}
// Set the default value.
pi.SetValue(model, resetValue, null);
```

Using HTML helpers, I can easily access the model metadata and suppress rendering of any fields the user does not have access to.

The kicker: I can't figure out how to access the model metadata anywhere in the **CONTROLLER** itself to prevent over-posting.

Note that using [Bind(Include...)] is not a functional solution, at least not without additional support.  The properties to Include are run-time (not compile time) dependent, and excluding the property does *not* remove it from the validation.

`ViewData.Model` is `null`
`ViewData.ModelMetaData` is `null`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
// [Bind(Exclude = "Dummy1" + ",Dummy2")]        
public ViewResult Index(ModelBindModel dto)
{   
    zzz.ModelHelper.RemoveUnwanted(ModelState, dto, new string[] {"Salary", "Ssn"});

    ViewBag.Method = "Post";
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(dto);
    }
    return View(dto);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to access the Model MetaData from the controller? Or a better way to whitelist properties at run time?

---

Update:

I borrowed a page from this rather excellent resource:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=687

With a model that looks like this:

```
[Required]
[WhiteList(ReadAccessRule = "Nope", WriteAccessRule = "Nope")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required]
[WhiteList(ReadAccessRule = "Database.CanRead.Key", WriteAccessRule = "Database.CanWrite.Key")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

The class:

```
public class WhiteList : Attribute
{
    public string ReadAccessRule { get; set; }
    public string WriteAccessRule { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> OptionalAttributes()
    {
        var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var canRead = false;

        if (ReadAccessRule != "")
        {
            options.Add("readaccessrule", ReadAccessRule);
        }

        if (WriteAccessRule != "")
        {
            options.Add("writeaccessrule", WriteAccessRule);
        }

        if (ReadAccessRule == "Database.CanRead.Key")
        {
            canRead = true;
        }

        options.Add("canread", canRead);
        options.Add("always", "be there");

        return options;
    }
}
```

And adding these lines to the MetadataProvider class mentioned in the link:

```
var whiteListValues = attributes.OfType<WhiteList>().FirstOrDefault();

if (whiteListValues != null)
{
    metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("WhiteList", whiteListValues.OptionalAttributes());
}
```

Finally, the heart of the system:

```
public static void DemandFieldAuthorization<T>(ModelStateDictionary modelState, T model)
{

    var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders
        .Current
        .GetMetadataForType(null, model.GetType());

    var props = model.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var p in metaData.Properties)
    {
        if (p.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("WhiteList"))
        {
            var whiteListDictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>) p.AdditionalValues["WhiteList"];

            var key = "canread";
            if (whiteListDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var value = (bool) whiteListDictionary[key];
                if (!value)
                {
                    RemoveUnwanted(modelState, model, p.PropertyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - excellent question. If no other solution is available, I suppose you could evaluate the user and model as the first step in the POST/PUT for any mismatches. It looks like your model contains enough metadata to make that determination. And of course, that evaluation logic would reside in a helper class, so it would only add 1-2 lines to each action method, e.g. `ModelHelper.DemandFieldAuthorization(model, user)`

Comment: @TimMedora -- Can you elaborate on "evaluate the user and model as the first step in the POST/PUT"? I'm not quite sure what you mean there.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Where did you get with this?

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble -- I took the day off work, so I haven't tried either solution yet.  I'll update the answer when I get somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap my interpretation of your question:

- Field access is dynamic; some users may be able to write to a field and some may not.
- You have a solution to control this in the view.
- You want to prevent a malicious form submission from sending restricted properties, which the model binder will then assign to your model.

Perhaps something like this?

```
// control general access to the method with attributes
[HttpPost, SomeOtherAttributes]
public ViewResult Edit( Foo model ){

    // presumably, you must know the user to apply permissions?
    DemandFieldAuthorization( model, user );    

    // if the prior call didn't throw, continue as usual
    if (!ModelState.IsValid){
        return View(dto);
    }

    return View(dto);
}

private void DemandFieldAuthorization<T>( T model, User user ){

    // read the model's property metadata

    // check the user's permissions

    // check the actual POST message

    // throw if unauthorized
}
```

Comment: Took me a while to get all of the pieces working, but I finally found something.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension method a year or so ago that has stood me in good stead a couple of times since. I hope this is of some help, despite not being perhaps the full solution for you. It essentially only allows validation on the fields that have been present on the form sent to the controller:

```
internal static void ValidateOnlyIncomingFields(this ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    IEnumerable<string> keysWithNoIncomingValue = null;
    IValueProvider valueProvider = null;

    try
    {
        // Transform into a value provider for linq/iteration.
        valueProvider = formCollection.ToValueProvider();

        // Get all validation keys from the model that haven't just been on screen...
        keysWithNoIncomingValue = modelStateDictionary.Keys.Where(keyString => !valueProvider.ContainsPrefix(keyString));

        // ...and clear them.
        foreach (string errorKey in keysWithNoIncomingValue)
            modelStateDictionary[errorKey].Errors.Clear();

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Functions.LogError(exception);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
ModelState.ValidateOnlyIncomingFields(formCollection);
```

And you'll need a FormCollection parameter on your ActionResult declaration, of course:

```
public ActionResult MyAction (FormCollection formCollection) {
```

Comment: If I didn't have a better solution, I'd have gone this route.  Thanks for the option.

Comment: I'll be examining your solution with great interest, thanks for sharing. Hope your app is awesome.